# Don't receive a long text message in loop

Tags: python, gammu

I' am trying to send loop of long text messages. I get only receive 80% percent of this sms on my own number. In the case of normal text messages, the problem doesn't occur. I would like to know what this is caused, I tried on several modems ...

This is my code responsible for sending sms:

````
def loop(url_get, sms, sm):
    list_sms = sms.get_sms(url_get)
    if list_sms:
        for send in list_sms:
            status = sms.long_send_message(sm, send['text'] + str(send['id']), send['phone'], 0)
            time.sleep(5)

            if status:
                msg = 'success'
                print(msg)
            else:
                msg = 'failed'
                print(msg)

            sms.post_result_sms(send['id'], status, msg, gammu.SMSCounter(send['text'])[0])

 def long_send_message(self, sm, text, number):
        smsinfo = {
            'Class': 1,
            'Unicode': False,
            'Entries': [
                {
                    'ID': 'ConcatenatedTextLong',
                    'Buffer':
                        text
                }
            ]}

        encoded = gammu.EncodeSMS(smsinfo)

        status = True
        for message in encoded:
            message['Number'] = number

            try:
                sm.SendSMS(message)
            except gammu.GSMError:
                status = False
        return status ```
````

Comment: Could you describe your problem in a bit more detail? There are a few ways to get only 80% of a message, does it cut off at some point? How many characters into your text does it cut off? How do the messages work if they have different lengths?

Comment: There isn't problem with cutting letters in the text message. I meant eighty percent of all sent messages, that is, it receives eight out of ten sms, this is an approximate value sometimes less, sometimes more. In case of normal messages up to 160 characters long I will get all of them.